# garbage collection of shared data in multiprocessing via fork

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I am doing some multiprocessing in linux, and I am using shared memory that is currently not explicitly passed to the child processes (not via an argument).

In the official python multiprocessing [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) at the "Explicitly pass resources to child processes" section it is written:

> On Unix using the fork start method, a child process can make use of a
>   shared resource created in a parent process using a global resource.
>   However, it is better to pass the object as an argument to the
>   constructor for the child process.... **this ... ensures that as long as the 
>   child process is still alive the object will not be garbage collected
>   in the parent process.** This might be important if some resource is freed 
>   when the object is garbage collected in the parent process.

this explanation seems a bit lacking to me.

1. When should i be worried about garbage collection?
2. Should I always pass data to a child because otherwise sometimes there will be unexpected results, or is this only a best practice?

Right now I am not experiencing any unexpected garbage collection, however this situation seems precarious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends strongly on *A) your data* and *B) your multiprocess [method](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)*.

TLDR:

- `spawn` objects are cloned and each is finalised *in each process*
- `fork`/`forkserver` objects are shared and finalised *in the main process*
- Some objects respond badly to being finalised in the main process while still used in child processes.
- **The docs on `args` are wrong** as content of `args` is not kept alive by itself (3.7.0)

---

Note: [Full code available as gist](https://gist.github.com/maxfischer2781/bb47e00f5d11453fd7249846184fb29b). All output from CPython 3.7.0 on macOS 10.13.

We start with a simple object that reports where and when it is finalised:

```
def print_pid(*args, **kwargs):  # Process aware print helper
    print('[%s]' % os.getpid(), *args, **kwargs)


class Finalisable:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Finalisable object %s at 0x%x>' % (getattr(self, 'name', 'unknown'), id(self))

    def __del__(self):
        print_pid('finalising', self)
```

## Early collection from `args`

To test how `args` works for GC, we can build a process and immediately release its argument reference:

```
def drop_early():
    payload = Finalisable()
    child = multiprocessing.Process(target=print, args=(payload,))
    print('drop')
    del payload  # remove sole local reference for `args` content
    print('start')
    child.start()
    child.join()
```

With `spawn` method, the original is collected but the child has its own copy to finalise:

```
### test drop_early in 15333 method: spawn
drop
start
[15333] finalising <Finalisable object early at 0x102347390>
[15336] child sees <Finalisable object early at 0x109bd8128>
[15336] finalising <Finalisable object early at 0x109bd8128>
### done
```

With `fork` method, the original is finalised *and the child receives this finalised object*:

```
### test drop_early in 15329 method: fork
drop
start
[15329] finalising <Finalisable object early at 0x108b453c8>
[15331] child sees <Finalisable object early at 0x108b453c8>
### done
```

This shows that the payload of the main process is finalised *before* the child process runs and completes! *Bottom line, `args` is not a guard against early collection!*

## Early collection of shared objects

Python has [some types meant for safe sharing between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects). We can use this as our marker as well:

```
def drop_early_shared():
    payload = Finalisable(multiprocessing.Value('i', 65))
    child = multiprocessing.Process(target=print_pid, args=('child sees', payload,))
    print('drop')
    del payload
    print('start')
    child.start()
    child.join()
```

With the `fork` method, the `Value` is collected early but still functional:

```
### test drop_early_shared in 15516 method: fork
drop
start
[15516] finalising <Finalisable object <Synchronized wrapper for c_int(65)> at 0x1071a3e10>
[15519] child sees <Finalisable object <Synchronized wrapper for c_int(65)> at 0x1071a3e10>
### done
```

With the `spawn` method, the `Value` is collected early and entirely broken for the child:

```
### test drop_early_shared in 15520 method: spawn
drop
start
[15520] finalising <Finalisable object <Synchronized wrapper for c_int(65)> at 0x103a16c18>
[15524] finalising <Finalisable object unknown at 0x101aa0128>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 111, in __setstate__
    self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock._rebuild(*state)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
### done
```

This shows that finalisation behaviour depends on your object and your environment. *Bottom line, do not assume that your object is well-behaved!*

---

While it is good practice to pass data via `args`, this does *not* free the main process from handling it! Objects might respond badly to early finalisation when the main process drops references.

As CPython uses fast-acting reference counting, you will see ill effects practically immediately. However, other implementations, e.g. PyPy, may hide such side-effects for an arbitrary time.

Comment: this might be due to the fact that you start the process *after* you delete it.

Comment: I have tested various sequences - deleting after start creates a race between usage in the `Process` and collection. Note that the issue with `Value` is implementation dependent - Windows and Linux (RHEL7) primitives did not show the problem.