# Python Multiprocessing Memory Leak in Ubuntu, but not in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to split and reorder data from approximately 100 files. The files contain information about approx. 400k users, and are ordered chronologically. The aim is to iterate over the 100 files and create an individual file for every user.

The approach is using pythons multiprocessing library to create several processes:
- One processing pool of workers, which load the data, sort it and append batches to a queue. Each batch contains data for one user.
- One process which dequeues elements from the queue and appends the batches to the queue

Now the code below works on a laptop with windows 10, Python 3.7. I am however trying to run it on a server with ubuntu 16.04 and python 3.5. While on windows the code works without problems, the server runs out of memory. Now the laptop has 8GB of RAM, whereas the server has 256GB. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I have replaced the code with a simplified version that you should be able to run. The code now creates processes, which add numpy arrays to a queue. Another process dequeues the arrays. During the queueing of the arrays, the size of the queue is printed. The queue size remains low since the elements are dequeued. The memory usage keeps increasing, however.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import multiprocessing
import time


def queue_remover(q):

    while(1):
        if not q.empty():
            data = q.get()


def queue_adder(q, unused_number):

    for _ in range(5):
        q.put(np.zeros((1000,1000)))

    print('q size ', q.qsize())
    sys.stdout.flush()

    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    list_of_numbers = list(range(500))

    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue = m.Queue(maxsize=40000)

    writer = multiprocessing.Process(target=queue_remover, args=(queue,))
    writer.start()

    processing_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3, maxtasksperchild=1)
    processing_pool.starmap(queue_adder, [(queue, number) for number in list_of_numbers])

    processing_pool.close()
    processing_pool.join()
    writer.join()
```

EDIT: I have just run the memory profiler to profile the individual processes over a time of approximately 2 minutes on windows, and 8 minutes on ubuntu. Please note that on both systems, the print of the queue size remains close to 0- elements are definitely dequeued in both.

[image: Memory profile when running on Windows]

[image: Memory profile when running on Ubuntu]

Comment: I cannot replicate your memory issue with your example code on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.7.1. On principle you can run into memory-issues with forking operating systems since it can end up in copying much more than needed. Try with changing the start-method to "spawn" for new processes with `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` as first line in the `if __name__ == '__main__':`-block.
Btw., you are needlessly running a cpu-intensive while-loop in your `queue_remover`. Skip the `queue.empty()` check, that's an anti-pattern anyway.

Comment: Hello Darkonaut, thanks for your reply. I have just tried adding the start method. The issue persists though. After only 4 minutes, 20GB of memory are occupied, and the consumption keeps increasing. :(

Comment: I don't know why exist this difference in different OS but I would recommend you to use `asyncio` because you are using a lot of IO operations and with multiprocessing you will have troubles with GIL. With asyncio you can avoid them.

Comment: What do you mean by "runs out of memory"? Does it swap? Does it hit ulimit? Does it hit OOM from a cgroup?

Comment: MisterMiyagi, sorry about this confusion. In the original,code using files, the server runs out of RAM, starts using the swap, and then shuts down/restarts. In the simplified code that is posted above this does not occur as I have just noticed. The memory usage rises to approx. 20GB, and remains at this level. I have just tried to run the same code, but replaced the q.get() call from the queue_remover function with a "pass". The memory usage runs up to ~20GB just like in the memory profile posted in the original post. The code then exits without error message with a printed queue size of 2500

Comment: The fact that the memory usage remains at 20GB is due to the limited number of times that the queueing occurs set by 'list_of_numbers' by the way. If the list is expanded, more memory is used. So this code would in fact reach the limit on the server, and cause it to restart.

Comment: @Earl Grey How do you run this? Which IDE or terminal?

Comment: I run it on the server through PuTTy with "python3.5 test.py". On win10 through the powershell with "python test.py"

Comment: @Earl Grey I don't think the fault is in the code. It runs fine for me. For you the queue gets drained but this is not reflected in memory. Your memory profile for Ubuntu shows one more child process than there should be (and is for me). Now my thought is if PuTTy somehow could be responsible for this. Just to make sure,  you observe the high memory usage also without running the memory-profiler?

Comment: @Darkonaut, yes, the memory issue can be observed without the profiler. Only started using the memory-profiler in order to find out what's happening. I will try to create a docker image after the weekend in the hopes of clearing this up.

Comment: @Earl Grey You're not alone with this.  We recently moved a process from Windows to Ubuntu 16.04 and are running into the same. exact. problem.  I'll contribute where I can if I see similarities.

Comment: Have you tried changing the spawn method from „fork“ (Linux default) to „spawn“ (the only one on Windows)? This affects the GC semantics. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504673/5349916

Comment: @MisterMiyagi We have and this didn't change the behavior for us at all.  One thing we noticed was that if you run a top -u ubuntu, it seemed to be hanging on to the processes even when they should have been finished.  Additionally, since each process was writing a result set to a file it was curious that every file in our 6 hour run had the same timestamp.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Same here. "Spawn" did not help.

Comment: With "spawn" you still get six child processes like memory-profiler shows? Have a try without specifying `maxtasksperchild`. @DataDog Are you also using PuTTy?

Comment: @Darkonaut We are using MobaXterm.  We have tried testing with maxtasksperchild with varying values or not specified at all.  When it did work on Windows build, we simply set our pool to number of cores -2.