How do python main process and forked process share gc information?
From the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504673/9191338 :

spawn objects are cloned and each is finalised in each process
fork/forkserver objects are shared and finalised in the main process

This seems to be the case:
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork', force=True)

class Track:
    def __init__(self):
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} object created in {__name__=}')
    
    def __getstate__(self):
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} object pickled in {__name__=}')
        return {}
    
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} object unpickled in {__name__=}')
        return self

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} object deleted in {__name__=}')

def f(x):
    print(f'{os.getpid()=} function executed in {__name__=}')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = Track()

    for i in range(2):
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} Iteration: {i}, Process object created')
        p = Process(target=f, args=(x,))
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} Iteration: {i}, Process created and started')
        p.start()
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} Iteration: {i}, Process starts to run functions')
        p.join()

The output is:
os.getpid()=30620 object created in __name__='__main__'
os.getpid()=30620 Iteration: 0, Process object created
os.getpid()=30620 Iteration: 0, Process created and started
os.getpid()=30620 Iteration: 0, Process starts to run functions
os.getpid()=30623 function executed in __name__='__main__'
os.getpid()=30620 Iteration: 1, Process object created
os.getpid()=30620 Iteration: 1, Process created and started
os.getpid()=30620 Iteration: 1, Process starts to run functions
os.getpid()=30624 function executed in __name__='__main__'
os.getpid()=30620 object deleted in __name__='__main__'

Indeed the object is only deleted in the main process.
My question is, how is this achieved? Although the new process is forked from the main process, after fork, the new process is essentially another process, how can these two processes share gc information?
In addition, does the gc information sharing happen for every object, or just the object passed as argument for subprocess?

on linux using fork start_method when creating child processes, python uses os._exit() (note the underscore) to terminate the child process once the function ends .... this is somewhat equivalent to the process crashing, therefore no destructors have any chance of being called, the process just terminates, and the OS just reclaims whatever resources were allocated to this process.
so you shouldn't rely on destructors being called by child processes to release resources. (for example to shut down an external server)

Thank you! I think os._exit is the key.

I think you are confounding calling subprocess.Process with start method "fork" with calling  os.fork directly. The if __name__ block is not re-entered in the child processes there: the suprocess code takes care of boilerplate code so that only your target function is called.
What makes "object being deleted" not to be printed on the subprocess is that this boilerplate code has to keep a reference to the object there: it does not get a chance to run its __del__ as the subprocess itself is shutdown at .join.
So, bear with me: (1) "x" is created in the parent process. (2) parent process is forked: "x" instance exists in the subprocess, with no need to be serialized or de-serialized, it is simply part of the Python interpreter state which gets cloned on fork; (3) The managing code in the subprocess module recognizes that and simply passes the reference it gets to "x" clone in the subprocess to the target function. This managing code has a reference to "x" in the subprocess itself - and when the target function returns, the whole subprocess shuts down: __del__ on the cloned instance does not get a chance to run - for some reason. Sorry, the docs say  __del__ is not reliable ("It is not guaranteed that __del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits." - ) , and I am not sure why the forking version of subprocess won't give a chance for it to run, which is somewhat the core of your question  - but x in the subprocess is not  the same x that is the parent process. It is a distinct instance, and reference counted independently. It is just that __del__ either does not run, or has its output suppressed - as it is called on interpreter shutting down, it is  even  possible "print" is not available in the builtins anymore, and the resulting NameError exception is simply suppressed (that is also documented).
The fact __del__ is not that reliable is known, and it even lead to the creation of the "context manager" protocol (the with command): if __del__ was reliable, it would not be needed, the finalizer code in an object __del__ would always run, and there would be no need for an extra __exit__ method.
So, here is your own code - I just added a new print in __new__ so you can check: it is indeed created only once on the root process, and added an attribute that is modified on the subprocess, so you can see it is not modified on the parent process:
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing
import threading


class Track:

    def __new__(cls):
        print("NEW Track")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, level=0):
        self.count = 0
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} object created in {__name__=}')

    def __getstate__(self):
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} object pickled in {__name__=}')
        return {}

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} object unpickled in {__name__=}')
        return self

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} object deleted in {__name__=}')

def f(x):
    print(f'{os.getpid()=} function executed in {__name__=}')
    x.count = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = Track()

    for i in range(2):
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} Iteration: {i}, Process object created')
        p = Process(target=f, args=(x,))
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} Iteration: {i}, Process created and started')
        p.start()
        print(f'{os.getpid()=} Iteration: {i}, Process starts to run functions')
        p.join()
    print(x.count)



Now, if you want a complicated mechanism to actually synchronize object attributes (and contained objects in lists and dicts) across processes, there is "subprocessing.Manager" - that adds an auxiliar subprocess and does a lot of things under the hood so that certain objects are kept in sync across different processes. It is so "magic" I never saw it being used in the "real world", the much simpler and straightforward solution of multiprocessing.Queue being preferred in practice. (I mean, there are people and projects that might use the managers, but I had not seem it, and they look complicated). You will like playing around the Manager with your print pid experiments though - go for it, you could learn a lot if this topic interests you.
Also, for "real world" scenarios when subprocesses are needed for Python code, take a look at  concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor  - it really takes care of a lot of edge cases, and makes working with subprocesses a breeze.

Thanks for your helpful answer. For "the whole subprocess shuts down: del on the cloned instance does not get a chance to run - for some reason", I'm asking for this exact reason. I think os._exit in another answer is the key.
